# Can't init webDriver locally with Selenium 4.1.2

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm upgrading the selenium version for my project (from 3.14 to 4.1.2) and I'm having trouble executing the tests locally. I can only reproduce this issue with version 4; if I change to version 3, everything works as expected.

When executing the test, the driver starts, but it fails due to a NullPointerException. After debugging a little bit, I saw that it failed doing `webDriver.getCapabilities().asMap().get("bundleID")`
on the method *getProjectType(RemoteWebDriver)* on *WebDriverInstance.java* because "capabilites" field was null.

With version 3, this field has values, but in version 4 the values are stored in another field, called "RemoteWebDriver.capabilities".

To create the driver, I simply do it like this:

`driver = new ChromeDriver();`

or passing by some already created ChromeOptions (incognito window, no cookies, etc.).

I'm not having any issues regarding the remote execution, however. Here's how I do it:

`driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, driverOptions);`

Where driverOptions are the same used for locally.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? It happens with Firefox browser too.

Comment: Capabilities are deprecated so you might check if chromeoptions has a similar method.  Caps are still available, but the get method might only be for remotedrivers.  (similar to "hascdp".. this method needs "hascasting" methinks...)  Remotewebdriver is the super-type, so when you choose "Chromedriver" it'll be set without that option?  I'm not sure "bundleID" has anything to do with Chrome anyway... what is that used for?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! About the bundleID, I'm not sure about what is used for, but the thing is it fails when it does the .toMap() (capabilities is null no that's why it fails and throws the exception).
I also noticed that the capabilities are deprecated, but taking a look at the code, even if I use Chromeoptions, internally it casts them to capabilities.